# Read /dev/input/event in android via Java programming language

Tags: android, events, input, key

I want to record all the input events done across the android phone, save it in some file and later use that file to see what user input has happened at what time. AFAIK, i should invoke
/dev/input/event* to get the input events. Please guide me so as to how can I do the same via an Android Activity.

Comment: You think you can get all the input given by the user anywhere in the system? How do you trust your phone?

Comment: I hope you have had a chance to look into PowerTutor App built for android. I am just trying to follow its shadow and dig down one level more to get these inputs.

Comment: I think answers to this question should assume the app has root access. Otherwise it is impossible.

Comment: Trying from device that has root access :) Any lights ?

Comment: @VnyKumar have you got the solution for this question?