# How to capture click coordinates on Android?

Tags: android

How to capture click coordinates on Android? I mean the X Y coordinates that are visible when "Pointer location" is enabled in `Settings -> Developer options`. The coordinates should be captured all the time, independent of what is currently happening on the system.

The coordinates should be either written out to a file, printed out to logcat, send through TCP socket or whatever.

Related question: [Read /dev/input/event in android via Java programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8786520/986533)

Comment: So, basically a keylogger? I'm 99.96% sure you can't do this with the standard SDK. It's a serious security risk. Are you willing to make a custom ROM?

Comment: Custom ROM - nope. However, if you have any idea on how one could accomplish this using custom ROM, I would love to hear it :)

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics, I just assumed that would be the minimum requirement, since you're dealing with a system-wide change of touch handling. You may be able to check into how the "Google Now" swipe works(from the soft key area, not the lock screen). I assume it must be listening to touches, but I'm not sure exactly how it's implemented. Presumably the soft keys in general do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 4 Jun 2016**: there is a tool for that, [RERAN](http://www.androidreran.com/). Its bug-fixed code is available in [this fork on GitHub](https://github.com/frankhuhu/RERAN).

---

There is a tool allowing for screenshot capture of avd / real device and for interactive monkeyRunner script generation with coordinates taken from mouse clicks on the screenshot: [wGetAndroidSnapshot](http://blogs.wittwer.fr/whiler/2011/07/01/editeur-monkeyrunner/)

One hackish thing I could think of is to capture coordinates of mouse clicks of the underlying OS and map them to coordinates of the running AVD on which the mouse was clicked. Even more hackish would be to capture screenshot  of the value of coordinates on AVD when "Pointer location" is enabled and to OCR them :)

There are also commercial solutions.

Comment: Hi,

Can you tell me commercial solutions

Comment: @Abhijit I guess [testdroid recorder](http://testdroid.com/product/testdroid-recorder#0) has to be able to do it somehow. Also, check out [getevent](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/getevent.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks Its working! Can you have any idea how to get relative cordinates of webview?